# Installing Omnipay with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, omnipay

I am developing an eCommerce website using Laravel 5.2 and trying to install [Omipay](https://packagist.org/packages/omnipay/omnipay) ( payment processing library ) via composer. But composer throwing the following errors when I tried.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install omnipay/omnipay 2.3.2
- Conclusion: don't install omnipay/omnipay v2.3.1
- Conclusion: remove symfony/http-foundation v3.0.1
- Installation request for omnipay/omnipay ^2.3 -> satisfiable by omnipay/omnipay[2.3.2, v2.3.0, v2.3.1].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v3.0.1
- omnipay/omnipay v2.3.0 requires omnipay/common ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/common[2.3.2, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.3, v2.3.4].
- omnipay/common 2.3.2 requires symfony/http-foundation ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
```

Please suggest me the solution how could I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omnipay is not yet compatible with Symfony 3 or Laravel 5.2 because of the dependency on Guzzle 3. Work is progressing on an Omnipay 3.0 release which will resolve that dependency. In the meantime I suggest developing your site with Laravel 5.1 which has long term support, and upgrade to laravel 5.2 later when omnipay 3 is released

Answer (score 3):

To use Omnipay with Laravel 5.2 you need to explicitly require `symfony/http-foundation:^2.8` before you try to require Omnipay.

This is needed because Laravel 5.2 uses `symfony/http-foundation:3.0.*` by default. However Laravel 5.2 is configured to also accept `symfony/http-foundation:2.8.*` which is also accepted by Omnipay.

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation [**here**](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#omnipay), there is one thing mentioned in `Important Note: Compatibility with Symfony 3 Event Dispatcher`-

> If you are using Symfony 3 (or Symfony 3 components), please note that
>   Omnipay 2.x still relies on Guzzle3, which in turn depends on
>   symfony/event-dispatcher 2.x. This conflicts with Symfony 3 (standard
>   install), so cannot be installed. Development for Omnipay 3.x is still
>   in progress at the moment.
>
> If you are just using the Symfony 3 components (eg. stand-alone or
>   Silex/Laravel etc), you could try to force the install of
>   symfony/event-dispatcher:^2.8, which is compatible with both Symfony 3
>   components and Guzzle 3.
>
> `composer require symfony/event-dispatcher:^2.8`

So, I have tried like this-

```
composer require symfony/http-foundation:2.8.*
```

After that, I have tried this-

```
composer require omnipay/paypal:~2.0
```

And this-

```
composer require omnipay/coinbase:~2.0
```

And everything works just fine :).